# Question about the definition of almost sure convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

A common definition of 'almost sure convergence' of a sequence of random variables reads as follows:

**Definition** A sequence of real random variables $(X_n)$ converges almost surely to the real random variable $X$ if and only if $P ( \lim_n X_n = X)=1$.

Written out this means that $P ( \{ \omega \mid \lim_n X_n (\omega) = X (\omega) \})=1$.

Now, I pondered about what exactly is meant by "$ \lim_n X_n (\omega) = X (\omega)$"?
Essentially, is convergence in $\mathbb R$ assumed here, or in $\mathbb R \cup \{\pm \infty \}$? The answer is quite clear because $X$ is a real-valued r.v.: It cannot be $\pm\infty$, as $X(\omega) \in \mathbb R$ for all $\omega$. So I assume the above definition indeed means *convergence in $\mathbb R$* (in this case, this is the only option that makes sense).

However, in other contexts, the random variables at play in fact are allowed to take on the value $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ (so that they are not "real-valued"). I first note that I have never seen any definition of 'almost sure' convergence for objects of this type (i.e., I've only ever seen it defined for *real* random variables.) Secondly, in such a setting where we allow for values to be in the extended reals rather than just the reals, what would the proper definition then be?

For brevity, I will call a random variable that takes values in the extended reals an *extended real* random variable.

**Definition** A sequence of extended real random variables $(X_n)$ converges almost surely to the extended real random variable $X$ if and only if $P ( \{ \omega \mid \lim_n X_n (\omega) = X (\omega) \})=1$. (Where, '$\lim_n X_n (\omega) = X (\omega)$' means that $(X_n(\omega)))_n$ is a sequence of values that converges to $X(\omega)$ in $\overline{\mathbb R}$.)

Does this definition make sense?
If so, wouldn't it then be better to define 'almost sure convergence' in this more general setting (i.e., with r.v.'s taking values in the extended reals) rather than for the reals as seems commonly done?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost surely has nothing to do with the range of the random variables.  It is a statement about the domain  (probability) space, i.e. the probability of convergence is for almost all $\omega$.